# Css and js not getting reflected in Magento 2.0.13 after installation

Tags: magento2

I tried,

Deleted files and folder from pub/static except .htaccess file.
In app/etc/di.xml - Replaced **Symlink to Copy**

But still no effect.

I am using ubuntu.
[image]

Comment: Have you deploy static content?

Comment: @SHPatel no, How to do?

Comment: See my below answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run below command

run below command for permission from `<your Magento install dir>`

> ```
> find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
> find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
> chown -R :<web server group> .
> chmod u+x bin/magento
> ```

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: I am getting error -  [Exception]                                                                                                                                  
  Warning: fopen(/var/www/html/Magento-2.0.13/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---814_CONFIG): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/h  
  tml/Magento-2.0.13/lib/internal/Cm/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 644

Comment: This is a permission issue on your setup. Kindly run this command chmod -R 777 var pub/static from you root folder for give permission.

Comment: when I run this command - find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; then it gave me result as chmod: changing permissions of ‘app/etc/config.php’: Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of ‘app/etc/env.php’: Operation not permitted....

Comment: Try run command with root user.

Comment: I have run all these commands in root user successfully but still there is no effect. In console it give me error - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Remove var/cache folder also check .htaccess file exist in pup/static.

Comment: .htaccess file exist in pub/static and also removed but still no effect

Comment: check all file path by ctr + u, is it okay ?

Comment: pub/static/version1497011846/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js - Most of the files does not exist.

Comment: What you say about : In app/etc/di.xml - Replaced Symlink to Copy

Comment: yes, I have replaced symlink to copy

Comment: Revert your symlink copy changes and check again.

Comment: reverted still no effect.

Comment: Remove var folder, check pub/static .htaccess file and deploy static content.

Comment: adding 'dev/static/sign' as 0 on the core_config_data table - issue got solved

Answer (score 0):

In windows sometime it is not work.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and clear /var/cache and /var/fullpagecache and checkit.

Comment: I cleared cache but still no effect.

Comment: remove pub\static all files except .htaccess file.
and run the above code again it will work :)